# How can I fix this if-else statement in my Batch Code to successfully run?

Tags: batch-file, pdf, merge

I have a batch script that merges two pdfs from two separate folders, puts them in a staging folder for me to audit, and then moves them to a company wide folder directory. I want to edit this script to dump the pdf from folder 1 regardless of whether there is a pdf in folder 2. Here is my original code which works perfectly. I know it may look weird but its intentional (like the destination variable being the same as the gisfolder variable. I do not want to change this at all. I just want to add an "if else" statement.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "pdftk=C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"

set "sourcemap=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central"
set "sourcetables=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Photos"
set "destination=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central Completed"

set pdffile=
set pdfattach=
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /o:n "%sourcemap%\*.pdf"') do (
    set "pdffile=%sourcemap%\%%i"
    set "pdfattach=%sourcetables%\PestManagement_TableSeries_!pdffile:~50!"
    set "outputpdf=%%~ni"
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" "!pdffile!" "!pdfattach!" cat output "%destination%\!pdffile:~50,-4! - Field Scout Survey Map %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.pdf"
    echo "Successfully completed !pdffile:~50,-4!"
)

set "gisfolder=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central Completed"
set "spfolder=\\sunpacific.local\lerdodata\Sun Pacific Public\6 - Business Units\Sun Pacific Farming Cooperative\B - General\10 - Maps\Ranch Maps\Other Maps\PCA\Maps\Central"
set "archivefolder=\\sunpacific.local\lerdodata\Sun Pacific Public\6 - Business Units\Sun Pacific Farming Cooperative\B - General\10 - Maps\Other Maps\PCA\Old Maps\Central"

move "%spfolder%\*.pdf" "%archivefolder%"

move "%gisfolder%\*.pdf" "%spfolder%"

cmd /k
```

Here is the code that I am struggling with. I know this is simple but I am not native to batch programming and every time I run this I don't get any errors, the command window pops up and closes before I can do anything. The only change between the two code blocks is the "if else" statement. Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "pdftk=C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"

set "sourcemap=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central"
set "sourcetables=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Photos"
set "destination=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central Completed"

set pdffile=
set pdfattach=
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /o:n "%sourcemap%\*.pdf"') do (
    set "pdffile=%sourcemap%\%%i"
    set "pdfattach=%sourcetables%\PestManagement_TableSeries_!pdffile:~50!"
    set "outputpdf=%%~ni"
    if exist "!pdfattach!" (
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" "!pdffile!" "!pdfattach!" cat output "%destination%\!pdffile:~50,-4! - Field Scout Survey Map %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.pdf"
    )else (
        move "!pdffile!" "%destination%\!pdffile:~50,-4! - Field Scout Survey Map %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.pdf"
        echo "Successfully completed !pdffile:~50,-4!"
        )

set "gisfolder=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central Completed"
set "spfolder=\\sunpacific.local\lerdodata\Sun Pacific Public\6 - Business Units\Sun Pacific Farming Cooperative\B - General\10 - Maps\Ranch Maps\Other Maps\PCA\Maps\Central"
set "archivefolder=\\sunpacific.local\lerdodata\Sun Pacific Public\6 - Business Units\Sun Pacific Farming Cooperative\B - General\10 - Maps\Other Maps\PCA\Old Maps\Central"

move "%spfolder%\*.pdf" "%archivefolder%"

move "%gisfolder%\*.pdf" "%spfolder%"

cmd /k
```

Comment: First two rules of debugging a batch file. 1) Turn ECHO ON at the top of your script. 2) Open a command prompt and run the batch file from there. DO NOT USE YOUR MOUSE!  This way you can see all the code execute and you can see all the errors!

Comment: You are missing a closing parentheses.  You need one for the `FOR` command. One for the `IF` and one for the `ELSE`.

Comment: Would it not be better to simplify the code, [like this](https://sebsauvage.net/paste/?d4fb5004c8d2e47f#2sHqFF8DdEDaR2+UnoftENygnyYkryyXMtMp6FDz9aU=).

Comment: @Squashman thank you so much for your support. That fixed it and it now works perfectly. Your note about testing is also really helpful, I will use that!

Comment: @Compo Probably, but this is my first rodeo and I'm just trying to get something that works. Thank you for putting that together though, I will look at it to improve my code.

Comment: The best way to achieve that is not to unnecessarily define variables within your loop. That's what the example linked in my previous comment does. It also handles the missing parenthesis too. Please feel free to try it, _(after you've taken a look at it obviously)_.